# How to avoid the if else code block to run when recomposition happens?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, state-management

There is a `AddOrUpdateCustomerRoute` composable , where user can add a new customer or update a existing customer, i have a nullable `existingcustomer` state( nullable in case of a new customer), and there are two more state `isCustomerUpdated` or `isCustomerAdded`, and i have used if else to show a toast message for both success and failure on adding and updating the customer, the issue is when the customer is updated, or even if new customer is added, the recomposition happens twice and the if else code block triggers twice and show the toast message twice and navigateback twice on successful updation or addition

here the code for Screen

```
@Composable
fun AddOrEditCustomerRoute(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    customerId: Long? = null,
    viewModel: CustomerViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    navigateBack: () -> Unit
) {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    viewModel.getCustomer(customerId)
    val existingCustomer = viewModel.existingCustomer.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    val isCustomerAdded = viewModel.isCustomerAdded.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val isCustomerUpdated = viewModel.isCustomerUpdated.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    
    if (isCustomerAdded.value == true) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Customer Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        navigateBack.invoke()
    } else if (isCustomerAdded.value == false) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to add customer! Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    if (isCustomerUpdated.value == true) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "CustomerUpdated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        navigateBack.invoke()
    } else if (isCustomerUpdated.value == false) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to update customer, Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
    }

    AddOrEditCustomerScreens(
        modifier = modifier,
        customer = existingCustomer.value,
        addCustomer = { name, phone, email ->
            viewModel.addCustomer(name, phone, email)
        },
        updateCustomer = {
            viewModel.updateCustomer(it)
        },
        navigateBack = navigateBack
    )
}

@Composable
fun AddOrEditCustomerScreens(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    customer: Customer? = null,
    addCustomer: (String, String, String) -> Unit,
    updateCustomer: (customer: Customer) -> Unit,
    navigateBack: () -> Unit
) {
    val isEditing = customer != null
    val title = if (isEditing) stringResource(id = R.string.update_customer) else stringResource(
        id = R.string.add_customer
    )
    val customerName = remember(customer) {
        mutableStateOf(customer?.name ?: "")
    }
    val phoneNumber = remember(customer) {
        mutableStateOf(customer?.phone ?: "")
    }
    val email = remember(customer) {
        mutableStateOf(customer?.email ?: "")
    }

    Scaffold(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        topBar = {
            DefaultAppBar(title = title, navigateBack = navigateBack, showSearch = false)
        }
    ) { paddingValue ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(paddingValue)
                .padding(vertical = 12.dp, horizontal = 16.dp)
        ) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = customerName.value,
                onValueChange = { customerName.value = it },
                label = {
                    TextH70(text = stringResource(id = R.string.customer_name))
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            )

            OutlinedTextField(
                value = phoneNumber.value,
                onValueChange = {
                    if (it.length <= MAX_PHONE_LIMIT) {
                        phoneNumber.value = it
                    }
                },
                label = {
                    TextH70(text = stringResource(id = R.string.mobile_number_optional))
                },
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            )

            OutlinedTextField(
                value = email.value,
                onValueChange = { email.value = it },
                label = {
                    TextH70(text = stringResource(id = R.string.email_id))
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            )

            Button(
                enabled = (customerName.value.isNotEmpty() && phoneNumber.value.isNotEmpty()),
                onClick = {
                    if (isEditing)
                        updateCustomer(
                            customer!!.copy(
                                name = customerName.value,
                                phone = phoneNumber.value,
                                email = email.value
                            )
                        )
                    else
                        addCustomer(customerName.value, phoneNumber.value, email.value)
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = 24.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.End),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer
                ),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
            ) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.PersonAdd, null)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
                TextH40(
                    title,
                    color = Color.White
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here' is the viewModel code

```
@HiltViewModel
class CustomerViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getCustomersUseCase: GetCustomersUseCase,
    private val searchCustomersUseCase: SearchCustomersUseCase,
    private val getCustomerUseCase: GetCustomerUseCase,
    private val addCustomerUseCase: AddCustomerUseCase,
    private val updateCustomerUseCase: UpdateCustomerUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
    
private val _existingCustomer = MutableStateFlow<Customer?>(null)
val existingCustomer = _existingCustomer
    
private val _customers = MutableStateFlow<PagingData<Customer>>(PagingData.empty())
val customers = _customers
    
private val _isCustomerAdded = MutableStateFlow<Boolean?>(null)
val isCustomerAdded = _isCustomerAdded
    
private val _isCustomerUpdated = MutableStateFlow<Boolean?>(null)
val isCustomerUpdated = _isCustomerUpdated
    
init {
    fetchInitCustomers()
}
    
private fun fetchInitCustomers() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        getCustomersUseCase.perform()
        .map { pagingData ->
            pagingData.map {
                it.toCustomer()
            }
        }.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
        .collect {
            _customers.value = it
        }
    }
}
    
fun searchCustomers(query: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        searchCustomersUseCase.perform(query)
            .map { pagingData -> pagingData.map { it.toCustomer() } }.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
        .collect {
            customers.value = it
        }
    }
}
    
fun getCustomer(id: Long?) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        if (id != null) {
            _existingCustomer.value = getCustomerUseCase.perform(id)
        } else {
            _existingCustomer.value = null
        }
    }
}
    
fun addCustomer(name: String, phone: String, email: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val request = AddCustomerRequest(
            name = name,
            phone = phone,
            email = email,
            amountDue = null
        )
        _isCustomerAdded.value = addCustomerUseCase.perform(request)
    }
}
    
fun updateCustomer(customer: Customer) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val request = UpdateCustomerRequest(
            id = customer.id,
            name = customer.name,
            phone = customer.phone,
            email = customer.email,
            amountDue = customer.amountDue
        )
        _isCustomerUpdated.value = updateCustomerUseCase.perform(customer.id, request)
        }
    }
}
```

and i think the extraction of state can be done better here, but i just can't wrap my head around how to do that, new to compose and this thing would have been a piece of cake in xml, but doing things in compose is new to me, as i am trying to learn it

I tried using side effect like LauncedEffect, but it didn't help at all, the code didn't even run so couldn't find much about what can i do here

```
LaunchedEffect(isCustomerAdded) {
    if (isCustomerAdded.value == true) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Customer Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            navigateBack.invoke()
        } else if (isCustomerAdded.value == false) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to add customer! Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}

LaunchedEffect(isCustomerUpdated) {
    if (isCustomerUpdated.value == true) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "CustomerUpdated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            navigateBack.invoke()
    } else if (isCustomerUpdated.value == false) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to update customer, Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks mandar for formatting the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `.value` to `LaunchedEffect` key.

```
LaunchedEffect(isCustomerAdded.value)
```

Or keep `LaunchedEffect` but switch to property delegation by using `by`.

```
val isCustomerAdded by viewModel.isCustomerAdded.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
```

Comment: used property delegation with Launched Effect, worked like charm. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This `viewModel.getCustomer(customerId)` it will call every recompose happens,
To ensure that the code call executes just one, you can use the following:

```
 LaunchedEffect(Unit){ // this it will execute just one
 viewModel.getCustomer(customerId)
 }
```

Or you can directly get the navigation param from ViewModel

```
 class CustomerViewModel(private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) : 
  ViewModel(){
  private val customerId = savedStateHandle.getLong(....)
  init{
  getCustomer(customerId )
  }
```

You can use `by` with `LaunchedEffect`. [In reference to my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77455541/13436099#12345678)

Some Tips:
To avoid unnecessary recompose, convert these functions to use function references, you can directly reference the functions from the `viewModel`. Here's how you can do it:

```
addCustomer = viewModel::addCustomer,
updateCustomer = viewModel::updateCustomer
```

When working with shared states in Android using Kotlin, leverage StateFlow to observe changes in values. [See Android reference](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow)

```
   // Backing property to avoid state updates from other classes
private val _existingCustomer = MutableStateFlow<Customer?>(null)
// The UI collects from this StateFlow to get its state updates
val existingCustomer: StateFlow<Customer?> = _existingCustomer
```

Comment: thanks shasho for all the suggestion, especially for the savedStateHandle method